# Distance of a point in angle bicestor

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I believe the distance of a point in acute angle bisector is smaller than that of the obtuse angle bisector. I need to know if I know the angle between two lines is it possible to find the distance on the angle bisec[image]tor which will be equal to the distance on the line?

Let us say OA = OA` = OC all of same distance. But OC will not be perpendicular to OA due to the angle. I need to know what correlation can i come up the distance CD and angle so that i can find D to make it perpendicular to OA.

[image]

Comment: What does "distance of a point" mean?  Distance between a point and *what?*

Comment: Hi Sammy, Sorry on that. I meant from the point of intersection if i find a point with distance 'd' i will find the point which will not be equal on the same distance if i calculate on the line. I need to know how the distance of the point varies from the intersecting point if i know the angle.

Comment: Wow! @RaajeshKotteeswaran , I'm afraid your "explanation" made things much worse...you really need to make an effort to make yourself clear, because so far you haven't succeeded.

Comment: Hi DonAntonio, I agree since this needs more graphical representation to explain . I am trying to put one in place so that i can explain much better.

Comment: Way to go, @RaajeshKotteeswaran .

Comment: @RaajeshKotteeswaran When will you put it?

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your patience. I have added the picture to represent my questionn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi / 2$ is the little angle at $O$, then by one definition of cosine in a right triangle we have
$$\cos\left( \frac{\phi}{2} \right) = \frac{|OA|}{|OD|}$$
so
$$\cos\left( \frac{\phi}{2} \right) = \frac{|OC|}{|OD|} \quad\text{ or }\quad
|OD|=\frac{|OC|}{\cos\left( \frac{\phi}{2} \right)}$$
This shows how the relative distances (from $O$) of $C$ and $D$ depend on the angle.

Comment: @RaajeshKotteeswaran Note that $1/(\cos x)$ is sometimes called $\sec x$ (the _secant_ function of $x$), so you can also write $|OD|=|OC|\sec(\phi / 2)$.